# Close a file opened by another process

Tags: vbscript

I am using an external method to validate an XML file. The problem with the method is that it opens the XML file and never close it so I have to close somehow the file. Does any one know if this is possible with VBScript?

Answer (score 1):

**DANGER!** Closing an open file handle of another process is likely to cause data loss. Only do this when you know *exactly* what you're doing. You have been warned.

---

VBScript can't close file handles by itself, but you can use the [`handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) commandline utility for this purpose.

```
filename = "C:\path\to\your.xml"

Set sh = CreateObject('WScript.Shell')

Set p = sh.Exec("handle """ & filename & """")
pout = p.StdOut.ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern    = "pid: (\d+)\s+type: file\s+([a-f0-9]+):"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For m In re.Execute(pout)
    pid = m.Submatches(0)
    hnd = m.Submatches(1)
Next

If Not(IsEmpty(pid) And IsEmpty(hnd)) Then
    sh.Run "handle -c " & hnd & " -y -p " & pid, 0, True
End If
```

If the utility is not in your PATH you must specify the full path to the program. Also, the program asks you to accept the EULA the first time it's run, so either run it once manually to do that or add the parameter `-accepteula` to the commandline(s).